# how to draw column with value=0 in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart where and I would like have a line/bar when the y-axis value is zero.. (that because zero is a correct value and null is a absence of value).is that possible?
For example in the column-basic chart (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic). 
is possible have a value=0 for tokio serie?.. so be draw it?

```
    {
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [0, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }
```

I tried  min property to a value less to zero.. but the bar is not visible...
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set minimum of yAxis below 0 and threshold to null (that way the columns extend from the padding Y axis minimum)
[Highcharts API: plotOptions.bar.threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.threshold)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4w23mrod/

```
...
yAxis: {
   min: -50,
   ...
},
plotOptions: {
   bar: {
      threshold: null,
      ...
```

OR

You can use [minPointLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.minPointLength)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-minpointlength-pos-and-neg/)

Comment: you save me a lot of time:)

Answer (score 0):

`minPointLength` is what you are looking for:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.minPointLength

Comment: Just as answer above says :)

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed it hidden at the end of the other more complicated solution in that answer ;)